# What mechanism causes a Kotlin coroutine to suspend?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, quarkus

I'm trying to understand kotlin coroutines, I'm coming from C# and there's something I'm not understanding here in kotlin.  In this scenario I'm writing a webapi using Kotlin in the Quarkus framework.  From what I can tell if I label a controller (or resource) function as a suspend function quarkus will automatically launch it in a coroutine.

The issue i have is i don't know what the preferred method for suspending that coroutine is.  The vast majority of examples I see on kotlin coroutines use the delay() function, which internally uses suspendCancellableCoroutine() to suspend the function.  That makes sense, but i don't see a lot of example calling suspendCancellableCoroutine() explicitly.  I've done some reading about the underlying code that gets generated in a suspend function, and some resources lead me to believe that by virtue of calling another suspend function i'll hit a suspend point and that will suspend my coroutine.  In C# i'd usually just call await() from inside my async function to execute the long running code.

In my kotlin setup i have setup an instance of jmeter and i simulate 5 threads calling my API at the same time, while limiting my program to run on a single thread in quarkus.  My API then makes a call to another API (i'll call that API, data API from now on), which could be a long running operation.  For the purpose of my test my data API has a 1 second sleep in it.

Essentially:

web api controller -> web api processing -> web api calls data api through client -> data API does slow operation

I've tried calling async/await on the call to the data API, which seems to work, JMeter reports that 5 requests are all completed in roughly 1 second, and the logging i have indicates that all 5 requests are handled on a single thread.  This feels clunky though.  I'm already in a coroutine and now my coroutine is creating a new coroutine (async is a coroutine builder) to execute the long running function.

I've also removed the async/await and updated the call to the data API to be a suspend function as well (though this is a client generated from resteasy client).  This also seems to work, but resteasy reactive could be generating something that's doing the suspend for me.  I need to work with a simpler example, but in the mean time...

If i'm not using the delay() function in Kotlin, and i'm executing code in a coroutine, what is the preferred method to indicate that a section of code is potentially blocking and my coroutine should be suspended?  Do i launch a new coroutine?  Call suspendCancellableCoroutine()? Or something else?  Probably overthinking this, but i want to make sure i understand this.

Comment: This helped me figure it out: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/the-suspend-modifier-under-the-hood-b7ce46af624f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coroutines library provides several suspend functions you can use to suspend in a coroutine or in another suspend function, among them:

- `withContext`
- `delay`
- `coroutineScope`
- `supervisorScope`
- `suspendCoroutine`
- `suspendCancellableCoroutine`
- `Job.join`
- `Deferred.await`

The typical way to convert blocking (long-running synchronous) code into something you can use in a coroutine is to wrap it in `withContext(Dispatchers.Default) { }` or `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { }`. If it's something you use repeatedly, you can write a suspend function for it:

```
suspend fun foo() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    blockingFoo()
}
```

but if it's some one-off blocking chunk of code, you can use `withContext` directly in a coroutine.

Note, using `async { }.await()` is basically never done. The compiler warns you against it. You should be using `withContext` instead. Calling `await` on a Deferred is used either when one coroutine needs a result from some other coroutine that has been passed to it, or when you're working with multiple parallel children coroutines inside a `coroutineScope` block.

The typical way to convert asynchronous callback-based code into a suspend function so you can use it synchronously in a coroutine is to use `suspendCoroutine` or `suspendCancellableCoroutine`. You can look up how to use those. They are pretty low level. Many libraries like Retrofit and Firebase already provide suspend functions you can use instead of the callbacks.

`coroutineScope` and `supervisorScope` are for creating a scope inside your coroutine to run multiple children coroutines in parallel and wait for them all.